# RapidMiner: Loop for attribute to extract value and trigger another loop

Tags: database, loops, rapidminer

I just started to work with RapidMiner and I am searching for a way to iterate throughone attribute, extracting the specific integer value and for each iteration triggering the creation of new inserts based on the integer value.

I thought it could be possible to use the Loop Values task. In the subprocess I would use the specific value of the iteration and then trigger a generation of a new data set. But Loop Values only seem to work with nominal values.

Moreover, how is it possible to define the number of iterations (e.g, for the function Loop) by using the current value of an attribute?

Any idea?

**UPDATE1:**

Loop Examples seems to be the correct choice for me for the first step, as Loop Values checks how many different values of the specific attribute exists.

**Update2:**

The part with the loops:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.013">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" name="Process">
<parameter key="resultfile" value="/home/test.res"/>
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="read_excel" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="1586" y="615">
    <parameter key="excel_file" value="D:\stack.xlsx"/>
    <list key="annotations"/>
    <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="loop_examples" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop Examples" width="90" x="1921" y="615">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="extract_macro" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="60" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="112" y="30">
        <parameter key="macro" value="macro_value"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="att9"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="1"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="loop" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop (2)" width="90" x="380" y="30">
        <parameter key="set_iteration_macro" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="iterations" value="%{macro_value}"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="45" y="300">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="person_type_id" value="3"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes (8)" width="90" x="112" y="120">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
            <parameter key="attributes" value="id|temp_id||att9"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="join" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Join (5)" width="90" x="246" y="255">
            <parameter key="use_id_attribute_as_key" value="false"/>
            <list key="key_attributes"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes (7)" width="90" x="447" y="255">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
            <parameter key="attributes" value="id|person_type_id|temp_id|att9"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="input 1" to_op="Select Attributes (8)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Join (5)" to_port="right"/>
          <connect from_op="Select Attributes (8)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Join (5)" to_port="left"/>
          <connect from_op="Join (5)" from_port="join" to_op="Select Attributes (7)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Select Attributes (7)" from_port="example set output" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="append" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Append" width="90" x="648" y="30"/>
      <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Loop (2)" to_port="input 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop (2)" from_port="output 1" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_port="example set"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="write_csv" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="writePersonref" width="90" x="2055" y="615">
    <parameter key="csv_file" value="/home/result.csv"/>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Loop Examples" to_port="example set"/>
  <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="example set" to_op="writePersonref" to_port="input"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
</process>
```

The test data just contains 2 rows: First row: id=1, att9=2, temp_id=2; Second row: id=2, att9=1, temp_id=4

The correct result should contain 3 rows: First row: id=1, att9=2, temp_id=2, person_type_id=3; Second row: id=1, att9=2, temp_id=2, person_type_id=3; Third row: id=2, att9=1, temp_id=2, person_type_id=3.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML does not import. Can you re-do?

Comment: There is a missing </operator></process> from the end of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert integers to nominal values using the `Numerical to Polynominal` operator. The `Loop Values` operator will then work fine. If you still need an integer value inside the loop, my advice would be to create a new attribute (use `Generate Attributes`) that is a copy of the original integer, convert that to polynominal and use this to control the `Loop Values` operator.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Or is there any other way to model my use case? How to work inside the sub process with each value of one attribute in each iteration? I need the value of each iteration to generate a new data set. If the current iteration value is 3, I need to generate three rows in my generated data set. Additionally, I need to insert the initial foreign key value in this new generated data set.

Comment: The current value will be contained in a macro (default name is `loop_value`). You can use this to control the creation of a new example set. The simplest way I can think of is to use the `Loop` operator with its iterations parameter set to the `loop_value` macro. Inside this operator, generate a single row for the data you want (try the `Generate Data by User Specification` for example). The output from the `Loop` operator is a collection of single rows that you can join together using the `Append` operator.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also any possibility to generate a new data set by using a value of the original data set? %{value} ist not working for "Generate Data by User Specification".

Comment: It seems, I still havent found the right loop operator. Loop Values only checks how many distinguish values the attribute contains. Loop Examples is not working as I can't access to the current value of the iteration of a specific attribute.

Comment: All is possible but it's a bit harder work. To get access to a specific value within `Loop Examples`, you use the 'iteration macro' parameter to choose examples inside the loop. The `Extract Macro` operator is the one to use inside the loop. For this operator, set the `macro type` parameter to `data_value` and you will get new drop downs that allow you to select the specific example for an attribute you choose with the value going into a new macro. This new macro can then be used as you like.

Comment: I have 3 attributes at this point. It is not possible for me to chose this attribute in macro type. 2 of them are working, but when I chose this specific attribute of type integer I am getting this error message: "No attribute selected"

Comment: Could you post a reprodible example. It's impossible to know what the problem is otherwise.

Comment: To make it more standalone could you include the whole process? Not many will have the time or inclination to paste the fragment into a working environment.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes.

- Extract the value to control the `Loop` using the macro from the
  `Loop Examples` operator
- Filter the original example set to include only the single row to
  join with the generated example set
- Output the original example set from the `Loop Examples` operator
  (this is needed otherwise the loop goes wrong)
- Move the `Append` outside the `Loop Examples` operator

Here's the process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.015">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="resultfile" value="/home/test.res"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="45" y="75">
    <parameter key="excel_file" value="D:\stack.xlsx"/>
    <list key="annotations"/>
    <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_examples" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="94" name="Loop Examples" width="90" x="246" y="75">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="94" name="Multiply" width="90" x="45" y="30"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="45" y="165">
        <parameter key="macro" value="macro_value"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="att9"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="%{example}"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Filter Example Range (2)" width="90" x="45" y="255">
        <parameter key="first_example" value="%{example}"/>
        <parameter key="last_example" value="%{example}"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop (2)" width="90" x="179" y="165">
        <parameter key="set_iteration_macro" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="iterations" value="%{macro_value}"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="112" y="300">
        <list key="attribute_values">
          <parameter key="person_type_id" value="3"/>
        </list>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="false" breakpoints="after" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes (8)" width="90" x="179" y="30">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="id|temp_id||att9"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Join (5)" width="90" x="246" y="210">
        <parameter key="use_id_attribute_as_key" value="false"/>
        <list key="key_attributes"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="false" class="select_attributes" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Select Attributes (7)" width="90" x="447" y="300">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="id|person_type_id|temp_id|att9"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="input 1" to_op="Join (5)" to_port="left"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Join (5)" to_port="right"/>
          <connect from_op="Join (5)" from_port="join" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Multiply" to_port="input"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 1" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 2" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="Filter Example Range (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Example Range (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Loop (2)" to_port="input 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop (2)" from_port="output 1" to_port="output 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_example set" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Append" width="90" x="380" y="120"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="write_csv" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="writePersonref" width="90" x="514" y="165">
    <parameter key="csv_file" value="/home/result.csv"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Loop Examples" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="output 1" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="writePersonref" to_port="input"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I am sorry for my late response. Although finally I find out a way by myself, but probably only because of your support. ;-)